# push_back failing in VC6

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I know VC6 is 20th century technology, but for some special reasons that's the compiler I have to use.

I have the following code, which works just fine in Visual Studio Express 2008 (32 bits)

```
while( sqlite3_step( stmt ) == SQLITE_ROW ) {
  int tmp;
  tmp = sqlite3_column_int64( stmt, 0 );
  if(DEBUG) { cout  << "KeyID - " << tmp << endl ; };
  keyIDs.push_back(tmp);
  if(DEBUG) { cout  << "Size keyIDs - " << keyIDs.size() << endl ; };
}
```

In this particular test case, there's only one record, so the output, as you might expect, is

> KeyID - 1
>   Size keyIDs - 1

However, if I compile the whole stuff (included sqlite3) with VC6 (32 bits), I have the following result:

> KeyID - 1
>   Size keyIDs - 0

keyIDs is defined as

```
vector<sqlite3_int64> keyIDs;
```

but we even tried changing it to

```
vector<int> keyIDs;
```

I'm running out of ideas on what can be wrong, so I accept even wild guesses?

EDIT:

We solved this problem by using a local vector (keyIDs is a class member). Somehow, some piece of code elsewhere that I don't feel like tracking was (possibly) corrupting the vector, rendering it useless. Why this is happening only with VC6? That will remain a mystery.

EDIT2:

Although I haven't got to the root cause, I did find another problem (in a different proyect) with a large string (2800+ chars) passed to a function. The function itself received something like

```
function("something"+largestring+"anotherstring")
```

and this caused a memory exception elsewhere (coincidently, with a vector). It was solved by doing

```
largestring = "something";
largestring += stuff;
largestring += "anotherstring";

function (largestring);
```

In conclussion, it seems that something is wrong when VC6 creates a large object in the heap, and this may corrupt memory.

I hope this helps someone who, like me, is stuck with VC6 and is finding obscure errors.

Comment: It's very possible that the implementation of `vector` included with VC++ 6 is broken. If I recall, its support for templates wasn't really all that good...

Comment: Really, whoever you're working for, beg them that they get you either 2008 or 2010... *beg them on your knees*. Of course, if it's a toolchain that somehow only supports VC6.. you're kinda screwed and have my deepest condolences.

Comment: I used VC++ 6 for a long time, and had no issues with vector.  Just for grins, try assigning the size to an int and then printing it.  I know there were some issues with iostreams, but can't remember the specifics as we never used them.

Comment: can you step-trace through it with the debugger?

Comment: @Xeo Begging in my knees is not an option... it is like an add-in for a tool that already exists. But thanks... I had a good laugh

Comment: @vines I will eventually. I don't feel comfortable with my "then we add some magic powder and it worked", but that should suffice for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this problem by using a local vector (keyIDs is a class member). Somehow, some piece of code elsewhere that I don't feel like tracking was (possibly) corrupting the vector, rendering it useless. Why this is happening only with VC6? That will remain a mystery.

Comment: If your member variables are getting corrupted, this is likely just the tip of the iceberg. I hope you're prepared for the next mysterious bug.

Comment: I know what you mean. Yeah... As soon as I end up firefighting this stuff I'll dig deeper. But thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 6, ints are 32 bits.

try using **__int64** as the datatype.

Comment: Also Make sure you have SP6 applied.  There were a number of fixes.